# Scarface Tony Montana quote meaning

Tags: dialogue, scarface

During *Scarface* Tony Montana says:

> You know what capitalism is? Getting f***ed!

What did Tony mean by this? And in what context?

Comment: I'm not following the VtC as Too Broad... This is asking for the meaning behind one piece of dialog, as referenced by the character making it. How on Earth is this too broad?

Comment: @CGCampbell Me neither but fortunately it is out of close vote review queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two scenes before the one where he makes that quote, Tony Montana had just met with his Banker to discuss the fees he was paying them to launder his money. Tony was making "ten million a month" and the Banker told him they would have to raise their rates, because of 'stockholders' and 'feds'. The Bank was charging

> (Xl Rev. l/18/83 151-B  CONTINUED BANKER  (Cont'd)
>
> *Tony, we   got   stockholders,   we   gotta go  ten  percent  on  the first  twelve million; that's  in  denominations  of twenty. We'll  go  eight percent  on your  ten  dollar  bills  and  six  points on  your  fives.*

Remember that the "ten million a month" Tony refers to is illicit drug money. It could not be reported to the government. So it had to be laundered to 'clean' it and make it usable income. This was what the Banker was charging the (exorbitant) fees for.

Then, two scenes later, Tony is sitting in his tub, talking to Manny, and watches a Bank commercial

> 158
> INT. TONY'S MANSION - BATHROOM -NIGHT - CLOSE ON (Xl TELEVISION   COMMERCIAL
>
> A   television   spot   for   Florida   Security   Trust   (or   Miami
> (Xl Security   Trust   or   Dade   Security   Trust   depending   on   legal
> options). A  respectable  business-type  walks  along  the sidewalk with a  nascent downtown Miami as a backdrop.
> Skyscrapers, glinting glass, cranes....
> BANK SPOKESMAN
> *Here at Florida Security Trust we've been  putting  your  money  to work
> for a better   America. We've been   around   for seventy-five years. We'll  be  here tomorrow.*
> A logo  for  the  firm  over  with  the  reminder  “Since  1907."

and then

> TONY
> *You  know  what  capitalism  is  -- Getting fucked*

From Tony's perspective, Capitalism is where the Banker holds all of the cards and he has to pay, to him, a large sum, just to be able to use, or spend, his *hard earned* money.

Answer (score -1):

Tony is saying that, in a Capitalist system, one cannot succeed by being nice and polite to the competition, compassionate or generous to one's customers, or expect favours from one's suppliers.  Everyone along the supply and demand chain are looking out for themselves and, in the process, someone is always getting fwk'd.

Tony's main motivations, throughout the movie, are to:

1. not be the one being fwk'd
2. retaliate against anyone who he feels fwk'd with him
3. and fwk everyone else while claiming he isn't being unreasonable in doing so...

[..as he just wants the money to get the power to chose his own girlfriend... but that's a different quote, "In this country, you gotta make the money first. Then when you get the money, you get the power. Then when you get the power, then you get the women" and ET video].

Answer (score -1):

Quite simply, Capitalism is you (the Capitalist) doing all the hard (and in Montana's case, dangerous) work, while the government/banks take a huge chunk of the money you've made.  Remember, the banks were laundering the money *for a price*, and then **on top of that** Montana still had to pay taxes.  He was getting hit on all ends, all while literally risking his life on a daily basis to make that money.